# How to trigger an event to monitor dataproc job status in cloud function?

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, devops, google-cloud-dataproc, aws-event-bridge

I am looking for some way by which I can track my dataproc spark job status from google cloud function in real time. I am not aware of any google cloud service which can fit in this situation similar to AWS lambda EventBridge (CloudWatch Events) where the lambda is triggered when a glue job state changes.

Please help me to solve this problem.
Any comments will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi @Faisal Khan, you can try [Cloud Operations Suite](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs) for your use case, Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track the real-time status of a DataProc Spark job from a Google Cloud Function, there are several options available. These include using Cloud Pub/Sub to trigger a Cloud Function after a job completes, using Cloud Storage events to trigger the Cloud Function when a job status is written to a bucket, using Cloud Logging to trigger a Cloud Function based on certain log entries, or using the Dataproc Jobs API to retrieve the job status and call it from the Cloud Function. The appropriate option will depend on the specific use case.